# Copy value of textboxes to another textboxes inside a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, copy

I have a textboxes on the upper part of my UI and a dynamic form below which contains the same name and should have the same value. I need to have a copy button on the dynamic form and copy the value I input to the dynamic form below. I am using angularjs. How can I possibly do that?

My HTML form is like this:

```
   <div class="form-group">                                           
     <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Brand Name: </label>
     <div class="col-md-6">                                           
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="bName" id="bName" class="form-control" ng-model="languageItem.bName" required/>
     </div> 
   </div><br/><br/><br/>
   <div class="form-group">                                           
     <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Product Name: </label>
     <div class="col-md-6">                                           
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pName" ng-required="true" id="pName" ng-model="languageItem.pName" required/>
     </div> 
   </div><br/><br/><br/>
   <div class="form-group">                                           
     <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Product Name Sub: </label>
     <div class="col-md-6">                                           
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pNameSub" ng-required="true" id="pNameSub" ng-model="languageItem.pNameSub" required/>
     </div> 
   </div><br/><br/><br/>
```

I need to copy the input value of this textboxes into my dynamic form below on button click

```
    <div class="text-left"><h3>New Languagessssss <button  class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="removeLanguageItem(languageItem)" value=""><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></button>&nbsp;<button  class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="addLanguageItem()" value="" /><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></h3></div><br/> <legend> </legend>
       <div class="col-md-12" class="pull-right" >                                           
                                                           <button  class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="copyText()" id="copyText" value="">COPY</button>

                                                        </div> 

<div id="web" ng-repeat="languageItem in LanguageFormData.language">
        <div class="row col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">                                           
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Brand Name: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">                                           
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="bName" id="bName" class="form-control" ng-model="languageItem.bName" required/>
              </div> 
            </div><br/><br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">                                           
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Product Name: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">                                           
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pName" ng-required="true" id="pName" ng-model="languageItem.pName" required/>
              </div> 
            </div><br/><br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">                                           
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Product Name Sub: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">                                           
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pNameSub" ng-required="true" id="pNameSub" ng-model="languageItem.pNameSub" required/>
              </div> 
            </div><br/><br/><br/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">    
              <label class="col-md-6  control-label">Featuressss: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">                                           
                <!--  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lFeature" ng-required="true" id="lFeature" ng-model="languageItem.lFeature" required/> -->  
                <textarea rows="1" cols="25" class="form-control" style="border-color: #FF69B4; color:#FF1493; border-radius: 5px; height: 50px;" ng-model="pfeatureEdit" name="lFeature" id="lFeature"  ng-model="languageItem.lFeature" required></textarea>
                <textarea rows="1" cols="25" class="form-control" style="border-color: #FF69B4; color:#FF1493; border-radius: 5px; height: 50px;" ng-model="pfeatureEdit" name="pfeatureEdit" id="pfeatureEdit"></textarea>
              </div>  
            </div><br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">    
              <label class="col-md-6  control-label">Ingredient: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">                                           
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lIngredient" ng-required="true" id="lIngredient" ng-model="languageItem.lIngredient" required/>
              </div>  
            </div><br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">    
              <label class="col-md-6  control-label">Instruction: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">                                           
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lInstruction" ng-required="true" id="lInstruction" ng-model="languageItem.lInstruction" required/>
              </div>  
            </div><br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-6  control-label">Language Category: </label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <select class="pull-right" type="text" name="languageCat" id="languageCat" ng-model="languageItem.languageCat">
                    <option value="">---Please select---</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="item in scpLangCat" value="{{item.language_name}}">{{item.language_name}} - {{item.language_description}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>  
            </div><br/><br/>
          </div><br/><br/>
        </div>
      </div>



I have these kind of codes in my controller file.

For the dynamic form:

    //** Dynamic Funcion for adding language form
        $scope.LanguageFormData = {};
        $scope.LanguageFormData.language = [
                { bName: null, pName: null, pNameSub: null, lFeature: null, lIngredient: null, lInstruction: null, languageCat: null }
        ]; 
        $scope.addLanguageItem = function() {
                $scope.LanguageFormData.language.push({ bName: null, pName: null, pNameSub: null, lFeature: null, lIngredient: null, lInstruction: null, languageCat: null });
        };

        $scope.removeLanguageItem = function(languageItem) {
            //console.log(subscriber);
            $scope.LanguageFormData.language.pop(languageItem);
        };
```

Comment: Can't see a copy button anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Icycool added my button already

Answer (score 0):

You should have a button which does the copy:

HTML

```
<div id="web" ng-repeat="languageItem in LanguageFormData.language">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="copyOrigin(languageItem)">Copy</button>
  ... rest of your code...
</div>
```

You will have a button in each element. To copy in THIS element the option to copy from origin.

JS:

```
$scope.copyOrigin = function (item) {
  item.bName = $scope.languageItem.bName;
  item.pName = $scope.languageItem.pName;
  item.pNameSub = $scope.languageItem.pNameSub;
};
```

Where `item` is the `item_i` in the list of elements.

Whit this code, basically, you will get the value from the origin form and move to the item received as parameter in the function.

You can check this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7ypP10YdsgHF3QNwJ01J?p=preview

In the plnkr.

- Version 1: Your code.
- Version 2: Code with copy button.

Extra tip:

- Vars & functions should start with lowerCase and be written in camelCase (Even those which are in the `$scope`

Comment: This is working fine but I noticed, the ng-model on the origin is the same as in the new language form. But I'm saving those data on DB and I guess I need to make ng-models different. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean with the `ng-model` of the origin is the same as in the new language form?

They are variables with the same name, based on your code. They are variables which the same value, based on you copy purpose. But they aren't the same. Try in the plunker next example: 0. Write `Option 0` in origin data and copy it to first item. 1. Write `Option 1 ` and you will se first item won't change. 2. Copy `Option 1` to second item. And first item will be option 0, second item will be option 1. NOT are the same values. You don't to change anything else. Which is your question?

Comment: The instances are different. They are copying the origin data to the item data. That's all.

Comment: @bleykFaust how is this going? Which was your problem?

Comment: I am using an angularjs dynamic form for my language and  I need to copy the value from the non dynamic form to the dynamic form. I used the javascript way to copy the value but when I save it to database, the value is not saved. My problem is I need to copy the value from a model to the model of the dynamic form and save it to the database

Comment: I think you can have a problem with the process function. Because It should work. BUT Maybe you can use `angular.copy` to make a copy of the data, and modify the rest of the information?

Comment: I updated the plnkr with an angular copy version using `item.data`. But I could notice the preview version is working cool. Why? Because I created 2 dynamics form. I wrote in the original form and copy to the first one. I re-write with different data the original form and copy to the second one. Each form has the data which should have. Why? Because they are working as different models. They are not the same model. You can try it. Also, you can check the process to the backend, maybe there is the mistake.